# Flutter: On Success Response dispatch from the store then only open the Dialog (showDialog)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to wait to finish the GQL call to complete successfully. On Success, I am dispatching the success response to the store. Here I want to add the condition to wait for the response from the signupMe function and success status which I am maintaining in the store.

Here is the code snippet of button click:

```
              if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                person.email = _email.text;
                person.phoneNumber = mobilecontroller.text;
                person.firstname = _fn.text;
                person.lastname = _ln.text;
                person.password = _pass.text;
                signupVm.signupMe(context, person);
                // Here I need to wait to finish the function call and want to add conditions
                _onAlertotp();
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  person.email = _email.text;
  person.phoneNumber = mobilecontroller.text;
  person.firstname = _fn.text;
  person.lastname = _ln.text;
  person.password = _pass.text;
  await signupVm.signupMe(context, person); // use await

  // this only runs after signupMe() has finished the work. 
  // you can now use your condition

  _onAlertotp();
}
```

Comment: In this case, This `_onAlertotp()` is not getting called at all!!

Comment: It only gets called after `signupMe` is finished.